# Microservices communication message templates approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, microservices

I try to realize microservice-based project on ASP.NET Core (Web API).
So, I have an independent components which communicate between them and external world. 
So, I have "connection points" between services - view model (input data) of one  is an equvivalent for request/response for others and so on. 
I think, there are some best practices for this case which allow me not to create tonnes of identically code, am I right?

Deeply, let's look at the situation, where I have, for example, data in the database, and microservice, which get (possible transform or wide a little) an information from DB and give it to an asker. Is it possible not to create duplicate code for storing and responsing information from database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you talking about are models. Input models and output models (DTOs).

If your projects are part of the same solution, then you can probably have a shared project or class library, to reuse your models.

If not, create a NuGet package, distribute it via your own feed and use it in all the projects that require it.

In order for this to work, you need to keep this project very simple. It should not have any dependencies preferably, so you can reference it without unintended consequences. If you keep it very simple then it can work well.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly **it depends** on your use case, overall intent and solution architecture.

Micro services are meant to be autonomous from a development and deployment point of view and they shouldn't know about themselves or know as little as possible. The more they know about other micro services the higher is coupling. They should owns it's model and data needed for what they're created for (in order to meet their responsibility). You can achieve this using, for example, [event based integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/integration-event-based-microservice-communications).

In this scenario I don't see a need for any code reuse. Every micro service will have different input and logic behind it. You should strive for this in your project.

If your micro services are too chatty (for example, they often need to ask other micro services for data), you probably made a mistake in their boundaries and you should consider design them again. Also you should avoid creating micro services which are just browsers for their databases.

Next thing to point out is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle, and why this is not applicable to micro services world. In OOP world is common to use this principle. That's why most developers will try to use it in micro services world. But if you would try to apply this to micro services you'll end up with high coupling and you won't be able to develop them truly independently. Code reuse and data redundancy is not so bad as you probably think.

So to wrap up. As I said at the beginning **it depends**. If your "micro services" are part of one solution and you're for example referencing them in code, you can't name them micro services actually and you can use solution like Andrei told. But if they are not and you really care about their independence (and you're following what I mentioned above) you should not share code among different micro services, and there won't be need to actually. But if different micro services really use same code (even if they're well designed), **don't be afraid and just reuse same code**. You'll see that it will pay off.

Micro services are not silver bullet for every need and you should be aware of it. As a further reference I recommend you this free [book](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/microservices-architecture-ebook).